# How to silently handle an exception?

Tags: nim-lang

I am calling a function in a loop and this function can throw an exception. But when there is an exception I want to ignore it and continue with the next iteration item. Right now I have solved this with a try and except, where I have placed some dummy statement under except:. It works, naturally, but I would rather have some explicit way of indicating in the code that I am ignoring this exception. Does Nim provide such functionality?

Comment: What you're doing is natural. Maybe you'd like to log some information on the catch method so you can have a reference to failed instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this explicit in the code, and maybe log automatically such errors or call special handlers, you could implement a template with custom handling to wrap that specific code. Example:

```
proc throwPair(value: int) =
  if (value mod 2) != 0:
    echo "Passed for ", value
  else:
    raise newException(ArithmeticError, "Bad value")

template ignoreArithmetic(body: stmt): stmt {.immediate.} =
  try: body
  except ArithmeticError: discard

template ignoreArithmeticAndLog(body: stmt): stmt {.immediate.} =
  try: body
  except ArithmeticError:
    echo "Did ignore arithmetic error!"

proc tester() =
  for f in 0..10:
    ignoreArithmeticAndLog:
      throwPair f

tester()
```